# How to automate satellite image downloads?

Tags: python, r, image, download

I am looking for a way to automate the process of downloading satellite imagery.  The screenshot shows the type and format of files I am interested in downloading (.ntf and the 150MB files).

I encountered the following code from [TheBioBucket](http://thebiobucket.blogspot.com/2013/06/use-r-to-bulk-download-digital.html) that looks promising, although the R package XML is obsolete.

```
require(XML)

dir.create("D:/GIS_DataBase/DEM/")
setwd("D:/GIS_DataBase/DEM/")

doc <- htmlParse("http://www.viewfinderpanoramas.org/dem3.html#alps")
urls <- paste0("http://www.viewfinderpanoramas.org", xpathSApply(doc,'//*/a[contains(@href,"/dem1/N4")]/@href'))
names <- gsub(".*dem1/(\\w+\\.zip)", "\\1", urls)

for (i in 1:length(urls)) download.file(urls[i], names[i])
```

**Is there a good way to automate the process of downloading .ntf files programmatically using R or Python?**

[image]

Comment: why is XML obsolete? What is wrong with the biobucket approach  (1) parse html 2) extract links 3) download links)?

Comment: What about the ntf files that are 450MB? Are those valid as well?

Comment: @Andy I am only interested in the ~150MB .ntf files.

Comment: @EDi I get the following warning regarding XML from R Studio: "package ‘XML’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)".

Comment: are you on windows? Read [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Status-of-installing-XML-package-on-widows-td4677482.html). XML works perfectly fine...

Comment: @EDi Yes, I'm on Windows.

Comment: Install XML from [this](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/) repository.

Answer (score 2):

Scraping is definitely easy to implement in Python.

```
# collect.py
import urllib, urllib2, bs4
from urlparse import urljoin

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.viewfinderpanoramas.org/dem3.html#alps"))
links = soup.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    try:
        if "/dem1/N4" in link['href']:
            url = urljoin("http://www.viewfinderpanoramas.org/", link['href'])
            filename = link['href'].split('/')[-1]
            urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename)
            #break
    except:
        pass
```

You might want to change the filename to include path where you want to put the file

Answer (score 1):

In `R` the `XML` package can facilitate what you need fairly easily.  Here's a place to start

```
library(XML)
demdir <- "http://www.viewfinderpanoramas.org/dem1/"

# this returns a data.frame with file names
dems <- readHTMLTable(demdir)[[1]]

# you'll want, for example, to download only zip files
demnames <- dems[grepl(".zip",dems$Name),"Name"]
# (but you can add other subsetting/selection operations here)

# download the files to the same name locally
# (change '.' if you want some other directory)
sapply(demnames, function(demfi) download.file(paste0(demdir,demfi), file.path(".",demfi)))
```

The only complication I can see is if the filename is too long (if it's truncated in your web-browser), then the filename in `dems` will also be truncated.